# String Operation

Tags: c++, string, function

Can anyone explain the `auto update_width = [&longest](string const& curr){}`
I was confused the way function declared and confused how function iterating data inside the file. File has a string of words and program finds the longest words which has most match of "aceimnorsuvwxz".

```
ifstream ifs("../data/letter.txt");
if (!ifs) return -1;

string longest;
auto update_with = [&longest](string const& curr)
{
    if (string::npos == curr.find_first_not_of("aceimnorsuvwxz"))
        longest = longest.size() < curr.size() ? curr : longest;
};
for (string curr; ifs >> curr; update_with(curr));
cout << longest << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Its a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function.

Comment: why the downvotes tho? If I had no knowledge on lambdas, and I would see such declaration, even using capture list, I would for sure be confused too

Answer (score 0):

```
string longest;    
auto update_with = [&longest](string const& curr)
```

Is a lambda function capturing 'longest' by reference and a const string ref as parameter and returns a string. update_with is in other words a function now.
You can read more about lambda here: [Reference to lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)